# Null model is a better fit for the data compared to experimental model?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, inference, glmm, likelihood-ratio

I have built a generalised linear mixed effects model fitted to a gamma distribution. I am wanting to compare this experimental model to a nested null model to see whether it is a better fit for the data.

Here is the experimental model for illustration:

```
fpMod_gamma <- lme4::glmer(reactionTimes ~ Condition + typingStyle  + Condition:typingStyle + depression 
                           + Condition:depression + Order + Condition:Order + (1 | stimulus) + 
                             (1 + Condition | participant), 
                           family = Gamma(link = "log"),
                           nAGQ = 1,
                           glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 500000)),
                           data = fpData)
```

And here is the nested null model:

```
fpMod_gamma_rl_null <- lme4::glmer(reactionTimes ~ 1 + (1 | stimulus) + 
                                     (1 + Condition | participant), 
                                   family = Gamma(link = "log"),
                                   nAGQ = 1,
                                   glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 500000)),
                                   data = fpData)
```

I then run `anova(fpMod_gamma, fpMod_gamma_rl_null)` to compare these models. However, the results suggest the null model is a significantly better fit for the data. I have significant effects in the output of my experimental model and I'm a bit confused about what this means for these significant effects - are they still valid? What conclusions can I draw from the experimental model bearing this in mind?

Here is the output from the anova:

```
                    npar   AIC   BIC logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
fpMod_gamma_rl_null   18 94932 95055 -47448    94896                        
fpMod_gamma_rl        47 94938 95258 -47422    94844 52.369 29   0.004957 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Any help interpreting this very appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you believe "the results suggest the null model is a significantly better fit for the data"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm basing this on comparison of the AIC of both models

Comment: AIC is not a measure of model fit. The p-value compares deviances and the null model has larger deviance.

Comment: @Roland Forgive my misunderstanding. I was of the understanding that the superior model is the one with the lower AIC value? So, because the models are significantly different, I thought the conclusion was that the null model accounts for significantly more information than the experimental one?